# AngularJS - Get reference to $rootscope in child window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to kick off an angular event in a child browser window from a parent. My first thought was if I had the module name I should be able to get a reference to the `$rootScope` from the angular global object but I have not been able to get that to work.

Does anyone know the best way to reference the `$rootScope` object from outside the context of angular?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have an id on your `ng-app`

```
<div id="app-container" ng-app="myApp">
```

You can get the `$rootScope` by:

```
angular.element('#app-container').scope()
```

Comment: yep, that's the ticket. Thanks.

Comment: I think you could also use something like `document.querySelector('[ng-app]').scope()`

Comment: this doesn't work when `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` :(

Comment: Well, honestly, I haven't tried it with that setting. Looks like this feature was introduced in v1.3. The documentation says this will disable `a reference to the current scope on to DOM elements`. Can't help you there.. Let us know if you find a way around this. I'm curious myself.

Comment: Hello, this is for getting the scope object when you know the element (#app-container). Is it possible to get the element when i am inside the scope? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not working with Angular as much anymore, but can't you just use `$rootScope`? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope