# How to get $rootElement from root Angular object

Tags: angularjs

My objective is to find the root element in an arbitrary Angular project if all I have is the `angular` object. This obviously isn't very kosher, so a hacked solution will do.

My first approach to this was to `find("[ng-app]")`, but this fails on bootstrapped apps. I've been playing around with the various angular modules, and I've hit an impasse.

I can do `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope')` to get the root scope. Why can't I just do
`angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootElement')` to get the root element?

Comment: You might want to reference my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075252/angularjs-get-reference-to-rootscope-in-child-window/17075408#17075408

Comment: Thanks! What I want is close to that but quite. Your answer makes the assumption that there is a DOM element with id app-container that happens to contain the ng-app directive. I want a solution without these assumptions. In fact, even assume there exists an element with the ng-app directive (and finding it via `find("[ng-app]")` is too much because this fails if the app is bootstrapped.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`angular.injector` creates a new injector function, it does not return the one associated with the bootstrapped app.

Services in Angular are singletons in the sense that they are only created once per injector, which means that the following code:

```
angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope')
```

Will create a new injector function and a new `$rootScope` every time it's executed.

The following line:

```
angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootElement')
```

Will create a new injector function and try to retrieve the `$rootElement`, which does not exist for the newly created injector.

You need to retrieve the injector of the current app:

```
angular.element(DOMElement).injector();
```

For your specific case you can for example find the first element that is associated with a scope and go from there:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.ng-scope');
var $rootElement = angular.element(element).injector().get('$rootElement');
console.log($rootElement);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/mQ5ZibnV0Jg8DreXn0w9?p=preview